# Error funciones y tablas

Tags: java, array, funciones

buenos dias.
Tengo la siguiente aplicación:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De momento el codigo no está completo, solamente tengo implementada la opción sumar, pero tengo un error en ella.
Para pasarle las fracciones al programa lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
System.out.print("Introduce el numerador: ");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        c1[0] = a;
        System.out.print("Introduce denominador: ");
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        c1[1] = b;

        System.out.print("Introduce el numerador: ");
        a = sc.nextInt();
        c1[2] = a;
        System.out.print("Introduce denominador: ");
        b = sc.nextInt();
        c1[3] = b;
```

Tengo dos tablas, **c1** y **c2** en c1 almaceno las fracciones y en c2 los resultados de las operaciones.
El caso es que para realizar las operaciones necesito sacer el **Mínimo Común Denominador** y lo hago con la siguiente función:

```
public static void mcd(int tabla[]) {
        tabla[0] = tabla[0] * tabla[3];
        tabla[1] = tabla[1] * tabla[3];
        tabla[2] = tabla[2] * tabla[1];
        tabla[3] = tabla[3] * tabla[1];
    }
```

Y luego para realizar la suma simplemente tengo esto:

```
if (op == 1) {
            mcd(c1);
            c2[0] = c1 [0] + c1[2];
            c2[1] = c1 [1];
            System.out.println("La suma de " + c1[0] + "/" + c1[1] + " + " + c1[2] + "/" + c1[3] + " es igual a: "+c2[0]+ "/"+c2[1]);
        }
```

Parece estar todo bien, pero al ejecutar la aplicacion ocurre lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver, la primera fracción la hace bien, pero la segunda no.
También me gustaría saber cómo simplificar las fracciones a la hora de los resultados de las operaciones.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Calculamos el mcm de los dos denominadores:

```
        mcm=1;
        i=2;
        while(i <= den1 || i <= den2)
        {
            if(den1%i==0 || den2%i==0)
            {
            mcm=mcm*i;
            if(den1%i==0) den1=den1/i;
            if(den2%i==0) den2=den2/i;
            }
            else{
                i=i+1; 
            }              
        }
```

A continuación resolvemos los numeradores:

```
   num1final=(mcm/den1)*num1;
   num2final=(mcm/den2)*num2;
   NumeradorResultado=num1final+num2final;
```

Y por ultimo realizamos la suma:

```
System.out.println("La suma de " + num1 + "/" + den1 + " + " + num2 + "/" + den2 + " es igual a: NumeradorResultado + "/" + mcm;
```

Tu código quedaría así:

```
    System.out.print("Introduce el numerador: ");
    int a = scanner.nextInt();
    int num1 = a;
    System.out.print("Introduce denominador: ");
    int b = scanner.nextInt();
    int den1 = b;

    System.out.print("Introduce el numerador: ");
    a = scanner.nextInt();
    int num2 = a;
    System.out.print("Introduce denominador: ");
    b = scanner.nextInt();
    int den2 = b;

int mcm=1;
int i=2;
while(i <= den1 || i <= den2)
{
    if(den1%i==0 || den2%i==0)
    {
    mcm=mcm*i;
    if(den1%i==0) den1=den1/i;
    if(den2%i==0) den2=den2/i;
    }
    else{
        i=i+1; 
    }              
} 

   num1final=(mcm/den1)*num1;
   num2final=(mcm/den2)*num2;
   NumeradorResultado=num1final+num2final;

   System.out.println("La suma de " + num1 + "/" + den1 + " + " + num2 + "/" + den2 + " es igual a:" + NumeradorResultado + "/" + mcm);
```

Comment: Excelente el cálculo de mcd(mínimo común divisor), solo que los numeradores no se deben sumar directamente, si lo arreglas quedaría perfecto

Comment: @Rocker13 Gracias por corregirme! fue un despiste tremendo... Arreglado.

Answer (score 0):

El resultado de las multiplicaciones en mcd lo estás dejando en los valores que estás usando para almacenar lo que has introducido por pantalla y con ello machacas los datos de entrada.

Por ejemplo:

```
    tabla[1] = tabla[1] * tabla[3];
    tabla[2] = tabla[2] * tabla[1];
```

en tabla[2] = ... usas tabla[1] que ha sido previamente machacado y perdido el valor introducido por teclado.

Yo usaría variables diferentes por que si los vuelves a usar ya no tienes el valor inicial.